# What regular expression i use for numerical and alpha-numeric

Tags: regex, html, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

Please help me out what expression i use in if condition to check whether the value of id is in digit or alphabet and i m using phonegap to develop a android app

In XML:-

```
 <cat>
    <id>1</id>
 </cat>
 <cat>
    <id>30</id>
 </cat>
 <cat>
    <id>ATTR11</id>
 </cat>
 <cat>
    <id>ATR2</id>
 </cat>
```

In JQuery

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "one.html",
                contentType: "text/xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                data: "",
                success: function(xml){
                $(xml).find("cat").each(function () {    
                  var id = $(this).find('id').text();
                 if(id == ??????){
                 var a2 = '<a href="#">'+id+'</a>';
                 $("#xyz").append(a2).trigger('create');
                 }else{
                 var a1 = '<a href="#">'+id+'</a>';
                 $("#abc").append(a1).trigger('create');
                 }

}

            });
```

Comment: Why not use `isNan()` to check if the value is a number?

Comment: or, since you are using jquery, jquery's `$.isNumeric()`

Comment: @Jbird plz help me where and how to write

Comment: The conditional `if(!isNaN(id))` will resolve to true if the id is a number. Alternatively, the conditional `if($.isNumberic(id))` will also resolve to true if the id is a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern matches only number values

`var reg = new RegExp('^[0-9]+$');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression pattern to check if id is number or not.

```
var checkId = new RegExp('\d*');
```

1. \d      A digit: [0-9]
2. d*      zero or more times